# Jenkins fails to download dependencies from github

Tags: go, github, jenkins-pipeline, goproxy

I am trying to download dependencies for go in the Jenkins pipeline as follows

```
stages {
        stage('terraform build') {
            steps {
              withEnv(["GOPROXY=https://${env.ARTIFACTORY_USER}:${env.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}@.jfrog.io//api/go/goproxy"]) {
              sh "go get testing"
              sh "go get github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"
              sh "go get github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"

              }
              withAWS(role: "arn:aws:iam:::role/-jenkins") {
              sh "gradle ${GRADLE_ARGS}"
              }

          }
        }
```

I see the following error which makes me think it is not able to reach out to github?

2`0:23:29  unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/yaml.v3": https fetch: Get "https://gopkg.in/yaml.v3?go-get=1": net/http: TLS handshake timeout`

Am I using the `GOPROXY` in the correct way?

Go version

Comment: missing info: go version , jenkins version , plugins?

Comment: were you able to resolve this ?